# show records that has matching UserAccountID and ParentUserAccountID and non matching records using self join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

I want to fetch the data from database whose UserAccountID is match with ParentUserAccount ID

Here is the Sql Query

```
SELECT Current.Status, 
       Current.UserID as UserID, 
       Current.UserAccountID as C_UserAccID,
       Current.Implementation_Type as C_ImpType,
       Current.ClientID as C_ClientID,
       tbl_clients.ClientName,
       parent.LastModifiedDate as PLastModifiedDate,
       parent.ParentUserAccountID as PUserAccID,
       parent.Implementation_Type as PImpType,
       parent.IterationNum as PIterationNum,
       parent.Description as PDescription,
       parent.GSheetID  as PGSheetID 
FROM tbl_useraccounts AS Current 
JOIN tbl_useraccounts AS parent on parent.ParentUserAccountID=Current.UserAccountID   
INNER JOIN tbl_clients on Current.ClientID = tbl_clients.ClientID 
WHERE  Current.UserID ='7' 
  and Current.Status!='2' 
  and parent.ParentUserAccountID!='' 
  and parent.Implementation_Type='4' 
order by  parent.LastModifiedDate desc
```

but i also want to show data in database whose C_UserAccID not equal to PUserAccountID

Any Help would be Appreciated thanks in Advance

Comment: sorry i made mistake on my own query now the problem has been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Current.Status, 

       Current.UserID as UserID, 

       Current.UserAccountID as C_UserAccID,

       Current.Implementation_Type as C_ImpType,

       Current.ClientID as C_ClientID,

       tbl_clients.ClientName,

       parent.LastModifiedDate as PLastModifiedDate,

       parent.ParentUserAccountID as PUserAccID,

       parent.Implementation_Type as PImpType,

       parent.IterationNum as PIterationNum,

       parent.Description as PDescription,

       parent.GSheetID  as PGSheetID 

FROM tbl_useraccounts AS Current

LEFT JOIN tbl_useraccounts AS parent on 

parent.ParentUserAccountID=Current.UserAccountID 

INNER JOIN tbl_clients on Current.ClientID = 

tbl_clients.ClientID 

WHERE  Current.UserID ='7' 

  and Current.Status!='2' 

  and parent.ParentUserAccountID!='' 

  and parent.Implementation_Type='4' 

order by  parent.LastModifiedDate descv
```